# POMDP books/lecture notes/tutorials

Tags: references, markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I'm looking for good references to learn more about POMDPs, preferably from a more mathematical stand point. The only good reference I've been able to find so far is:

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~darius/papers/POMDP_survey.pdf

which does a good job, I'm wondering if people could recommend more references.

Comment: http://pomdp.org/tutorial/index.html, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There is a short section (17.2) in the [RL Book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) by Sutton and Barto. They also have a bibliographic commentary after each chapter with some pointers.